# How to add an array to dictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to add an array to dictionary but I am getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[[String : String]]' to expected dictionary value type 'Array

Here is my implementation:

```
let dicContent:[String: String] = ["Alabama": "Montgomery", "Alaska":"Juneau","Arizona":"Phoenix"]
var myArray:Array = [[String: String]]()
myArray.append(dicContent)
let mainDict:[String:Array] = ["MainDictionary": myArray]
```

I get the error on this line `let mainDict:[String:Array] = ["MainDictionary": myArray]`

Any of you may know why I am getting this error or way around this?

Comment: When using **Swift**, first rule to keep in mind: ___don't annotate `type` where it can be inferred___.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `Array` keyword for defining type of dictionary. Try following to fix your issues:

```
let dicContent: [String: String] = ["Alabama": "Montgomery", "Alaska":"Juneau","Arizona":"Phoenix"]
var myArray = [[String: String]]()
myArray.append(dicContent)
let mainDict: [String: [[String: String]]] = ["MainDictionary": myArray]
```

Tho, types of variables can be implicitly defined in this case, so your code can be simplified to following:

```
let dicContent = ["Alabama": "Montgomery", "Alaska":"Juneau","Arizona":"Phoenix"]
let mainDict = ["MainDictionary": [dicContent]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says, you have declared the mainDict as

```
let mainDict:[String:Array]
```

but did not specify what does the Array holds. Either you can try one of the following to fix the issue.

try:

```
let dicContent:[String: String] = ["Alabama": "Montgomery", "Alaska":"Juneau","Arizona":"Phoenix"]
var myArray = [[String: String]]()
myArray.append(dicContent)
let mainDict:[String:[[String: String]]] = ["MainDictionary": myArray]
```

or if you want to use the Array keyword, you can do it like:

```
let dicContent:[String: String] = ["Alabama": "Montgomery", "Alaska":"Juneau","Arizona":"Phoenix"]
var myArray = Array<[String: String]>()
myArray.append(dicContent)
let mainDict:[String:Array<[String:String]>] = ["MainDictionary": myArray]
```

or simply

```
let mainDict = ["MainDictionary": myArray]
```

When you use the Array Keyword, you need to specify what type of objects that array will hold within the < ... >

Answer (score 1):

```
let dicContent:[String: String] = ["Alabama": "Montgomery", 
"Alaska":"Juneau","Arizona":"Phoenix"]
var myArray  = [[String: String]]()
myArray.append(dicContent)
let mainDict:[String:Any] = ["MainDictionary": myArray]
let getArrayBack = mainDict["MainDictionary"] as! [[String:String]]
```

Comment: Please don't post just code with no explanation. A good answer explains what was wrong and it explains how the answer fixes the issue.